# Selecting the appropriate analysis method for data with multiple observations for one subject

Tags: r, methodology

I have a data frame whith head looking like this:

```
    SUBJECT_ID   NLR1      NLR2      AGE      SEX      BMI      DAYS_OF_THERAPY  SMOKING
       1       2.9731183 3.3028571 24.10411   Female  19.11111        136        FALSE
       2       3.7941176 1.6904762 44.65753   Male    24.75000        40         FALSE
       3       0.4871245 0.7002584 33.30411   Male    20.74755        25         TRUE
       3       0.5225653 0.6234097 32.79178   Male    23.62029        24         TRUE
       3       0.6386364 2.0526316 32.27123   Male    23.30109        24         TRUE
```

These are data from various, often distant in time hospitalizations. The key variables are NLR1 and NLR2. The first one was measured at the beginning of hospitalization. The second measurement took place at the end of hospitalization. The time between the two measurements is different for each observation. It also happens that one subject has more than one observation, which could possibly affect the results of the analysis. Variables such as SEX, BMI and SMOKING status may further influence NLR and I would like to include this in the analysis.

I would like to determine whether:

- Is it possible to predict the NLR2 score using other variables?
- Does NLR1 and NLR2 differ significantly in the entire population?
- Is it possible to isolate subpopulations that, taking into account
  corrections for other variables, differ in how the NLR changes during
  hospitalization?

What analytical methods and what R packages would be most appropriate to solve this problem?

EDIT: I have have circa 60 different subjects and circa 100 observations.

Comment: I think one important thing missing from your question is how many observations you have.

Comment: I updated the main post with this info.